# Map a dozen of hierarchical objejcts with AutoMapper to DTOs

Tags: c#, automapper, automapper-3

I have a hierarchy of 12 entity framework objects.

I have also for each entity a DTO created.

I want to send the DTOs over the wire.

I have to use the DTO-approach.

How would you map this amount of objects with Automapper?

Do I have to use 12 times the AutoMapper.Map method?

UPDATE

I get this error now:

```
{"Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.\r\n\r\n....
I have an NumberEntity.cs with 3 complex properties which I want to map to

a NumberDTO.cs with 3 complex properties.
```

Is that not possible? Do I have to setup an extra mapping for complex classes within a class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you have to create a mapping for each DTO in config.

Let's say you have a `Person.cs`, `Address.cs`, `Car` and User in your `Entities`

```
public class User
{
public int UserId {get;set;}
public string UserName {get;set;}

public PersonDTO Person {get;set;}
}

public class Person
{
public int PersonID {get;set;}
public string Name {get;set;}

public Address Address {get;set;}
public Car Car {get; set;}

}
```

So you also have `PersonDTO`, `AddressDTO`, and `CarDTO`

e.g.

```
    public class UserDTO
    {
    public int UserId {get;set;}
    public string UserName {get;set;}

// HERE IF YOU HAVE:
// public PersonDTO MyPerson {get;set;}
// IT WILL NOT MAP
// Property Names should match

    public PersonDTO Person {get;set;}

    }


public class PersonDTO
{
   public int PersonID {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}

   public AddressDTO Address {get;set;}
   public CarDTO Car {get;set;}

}
```

Your class where you have all Mappings defined.

```
public class MapperConfig
{
  public static void CreateMappings()
  {
        Mapper.CreateMap<UserDTO, Entities.User>().ReverseMap();
        Mapper.CreateMap<PersonDTO, Entities.Person>().ReverseMap();

        Mapper.CreateMap<AddressDTO, Entities.Address>().ReverseMap();
        Mapper.CreateMap<CarDTO, Entities.Car>().ReverseMap();
  }
}
```

then in you code:

```
UserDTO user = Mapper.Map<UserDTO>(context.Users.First(s => s.UserId == 1));
```

To Map a List:

```
List<UserDTO> users = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<UserDTO>>(context.Users).ToList();
```

As long as the Name of the Properties are the same they should map.

Comment: Does reverseMap mean it is configured in both directions?

Comment: This is the Syntax: AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<SourceClass, DestinationClass>(); http://cpratt.co/using-automapper-creating-mappings/

Comment: Oh I want that but... the reverse mapping is done on the other side , the wcf server. Does the reverse still work? :P

Comment: I am not sure, I think you will have to create the mappings both on Client and Server side. Or put it in a Common Library and share between client and server

Answer (score 2):

If you have inheritance hierarchy then use this approach https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Mapping-inheritance. You need to register mapping for each pair of types and call *.Map* only once. If you have nested objects, then use this one https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Nested-mappings. Again, only one *.Map* call. If you posted some examples of your object hierarchy it would be easier to tell.

To sum up, you have to have mapping for each 'complex' type.